Read body as bytes using Hyper release 1.4
A long awaited upgrade to hyper 1.4 (from pre release possibly 0.13 ) has been successful except for one outstanding issue: Reading the body.
It is no longer possible to read the request body as bytes using

hyper::body::to_bytes(req)

Does anyone have experience with the release or latest version of hyper reading the body?
Noting the body contain json data which was converted to a str in the following fashion
std::str::from_utf8(&bytes)
json::parse(data)


Some clues are found in the echo example.
The following on line 64 of the above code provided the needed fruit.
let whole_body = req.collect().await?.to_bytes();

where req: Request<hyper::body::Incoming> opposed to req: Request<Body> in pre 1.0 release and use http_body_util::BodyExt;

Should probably mention that .collect() only works because http_body_util::BodyExt was in scope. That's what provides the method.

fairy nuff. i will add said use
